# Array index out of bounds error Pawn

Tags: pawn, sa-mp

I am using spawn points but when it compiles I'm getting this error:

```
Array index out of bounds
```

On this line is the error

```
for(new i =0 ; i < 5 ;i++) {
    SetPlayerPos(playerid, spawnpoints[i][0], spawnpoints[i][1], spawnpoints[i][2]);
}
```

Hoping somebody knows the solution to the error.

Comment: spawnpoints is from tutorial from samp for random spawn player locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array spawnpoints has either less than 5 entries or one of the arrays (`spawnpoints[0]`, `spawnpoints[1]`, `spawnpoints[2]`, `spawnpoints[3]`, `spawnpoints[4]`) has less than 3 entries. Try debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 5 with `sizeof(spawnpoints)`. If you still get the error after this, then your spawnpoints array doesn't contain an x, y and z coordinate (and so is incorrectly structured.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SetPlayerPos(playerid, Float:x, Float:y, Float:z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are spawnpoints defined with Float?

```
new Float:OldPos[MAX_PLAYERS][3];
```

Try with this example:

```
new Float:OldPos[MAX_PLAYERS][3];
GetPlayerPos(i, OldPos[i][0], OldPos[i][1], OldPos[i][2]);
```